# Pass variable from javascript to django template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to send a string value as a javascript variable from client side to be used in the django-template. Specifically, the string is the relative path of an image and it is to be used in the django template with the django template tag static. The static files are on Amazon S3 and should be served using the static tag of django template.

In django template, I need the variable photo_url from javascript.

```
<img class = "main-img" src = "{% static photo_url %}" alt="main photo" />
```

For now, In javascript, I have embedded the innerhtml of a span with photo_url as relative url of photo(/static/images/abc.png):

```
<img class = "main-img" src = ' + photo_url + ' alt="main photo" />
```

But this way, I cannot serve static files from S3 even if I include the static tag in the innerhtml in javascript. What is the best way to do that(pass javascript variable to django template)?

Comment: Pass javascript variable FROM WHERE?

Comment: From sth.js file which is loaded in the django template

Comment: Why not sending it from the view?

Comment: I just need it that way....the variable is obtained from a restful api via get request

Comment: sounds like you have order of events all backwards...javascript won't run until template has already been delivered to browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% static %}` is just a convenience tag, you can hardcode your static url anytime.
You will not be able to use js variables (either appending them or anyhow) in `{% static %}` tag because js gets rendered along with html without any processing.

Comment: so, can I hardcode the {% static %} tag from my javascript? Will that work?

Comment: No, you can't. What I mean you don't really must use it and can always hardcode the url instead. That goes to your statement `The static files are on Amazon S3 and should be served using the static tag of django template.`

Answer (score 0):

If `STATIC_URL` is available in your template you can set global JS variable to store it like:

```
<script>
STATIC_URL = '{{ STATIC_URL }}';
</script>
```

Then wrap creation of photo url in function

```
function photo_url(photo) {
    return STATIC_URL + photo_url;
}
```

This way you'll be able to achieve what you want.

Alternatively you can define [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) method on your models to provide full url with domain.

Comment: I guess you've misunderstood the question a bit. @Santosh Ghimire wants the image to be rendered in his template, not just to have an access to the url in js.

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich, I've read the question for the third time and think this is the way to be. May be I'm wrong.